# Invoke AWS Step Function from AWS Lambda Proxy (AWS API Gateway) .NET SAM Template

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions, aws-serverless

I have a AWS API Gateway, deployed using SAM template. The API request comes to the    Proxy Lambda Function. From there I need to call a AWS Step Function which invokes multiple Lambda Functions. I have multiple Solutions. Following Microservices pattern. Need to call one microservice from another. Each Microservice is in a seperate solution and the startup project is a ClassLibrary(.NET Core 2.1). Using SAM template and deploying it via AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio. Not using Fargate Containers and WebApi projects. Need to coordinate between API Gateways.

Comment: Your question, especially, the multiple solutions you have are not clear. Please clarify what are you looking for & what options you are considering.

Comment: Every microservice is in a seperate Solution (.sln). I want to make a flow like => API Gateway => ProxyLambda => StepFunction => Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say: "The API request comes to the Proxy Lambda Function. From there I need to call a AWS Step Function". It is simple, here an example of api gateway that use a lambda like authorizer and in the method execution I call a step function. In your step function later you manage your flow and your and the lambdas that you need execute
[image]